# Angular js ng-repeat not working for server response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an response object from the server like this

```
$scope.new = {"Module":"A","Link":"B"}
```

How do I use ng-repeat to display this two items?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in new">
    {{item}} -- {{item.Module}} -- {{item.Link}}
</div>
```

Comment: You would typically use `ng-repeat` to iterate over an array of objects.  This looks like you want to show the contents of one object so it would be just a `div` with `{{new.module}}`, and `{{new.link}}`

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense. Are you trying to use `ng-repeat` over each property within an object? Because `ng-repeat` is mostly used for collections. You just have 1 object with several properties in it. A better use case would be `[{ module: 'A', link: 'B' },{ module: 'C', link: 'D'}]`. You might use something like `Module: {{item.Module}}, Link: {{item.Link}}` for your current example.

Comment: How can I convert an object of the format {"Module":"A","Link":"B"} to JSON [{ module: 'A', link: 'B' },{ module: 'C', link: 'D'}]

Comment: Those are both JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). Can you be exactly clear what you're trying to achieve? The example that I gave was simply to demonstrate a regular use-case for `ng-repeat`, although as illustrated in my answer, there is also an `ng-repeat` way of solving your problem as well. Just note that using `ng-repeat` like the way you are will not loop over the object properties in order, the browser will usually determine alphabetical order as fit, as JSON does not keep key orders like you have defined in your scope.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wanted to use ng-repeat and the format to be in [{ module: 'A', link: 'B' },{ module: 'C', link: 'D'}].  Used 
var modArr = new Array();
modArr.push(new);

Comment: Then that's not something you'd typically solve on the client side through Angular. That's a server-side question, and you'd need to paste some server-side code which is currently generating `{"Module":"A","Link":"B"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to iterate through each property within an object:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,item) in new">
  {{ key }}: {{ item }}
</div>
```

Note that we're using `(key,item)` instead of `item` so we have access to the key of that property.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tmLLcM9DmPzTy25L8Fdl?p=preview)